# Using regular expression for reformatting a time

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am looking to automate ingesting some data but the format of the time I've scraped for each row is different to what I need.

The data I scrape comes like this

- 9a.m.–5p.m.
- Open 24 hours

It should look like the below:

- 09:00AM,05:00AM
- {empty}

So far I have the below that only works for the second attribute, I'm struggling with the time reformatting and doing it in the same regex.

> [str_replace(array("Open 24 Hours"),array(""),{import_element[1]})]

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data has just hours (not minutes in the input string), this should work:

```
import re

def process_match(m):
    n = m[:-4]
    AmPm = m[-4:].replace(".", "").upper()
    if len(n) == 1:
        res = f"0{n}:00{AmPm}"
    else:
        res = f"{n}:00{AmPm}"
    return res
    

inpt = "9a.m.–5p.m."
matches = re.findall(r"\d[ap].m.", inpt)

print(f"{process_match(matches[0])},{process_match(matches[1])}")
```

Comment: thanks, I'm getting an error in my log with call to undefined function "import re def process_match". Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: well did you run the code defining the function?

Comment: I'm new to this so still learning the ropes. I'm running this in a wordpress add-on, I can't see any where to define a function. Appreciate your help!